# How to categorise the following email types according to Gmail categories?

Tags: gmail

In my account, the following email types are not automatically categorised by [Gmail's tab feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016?hl=en):

- Customer support confirmations. Example subject: "Ticket Received - [#3014] Status of Customizable send times"
- Bugtracker emails. Example subject: "Launchpad [Bug 1473071] Re: Tray icon to pause/resume with a single click"
- RSS daily digests. Example subject: "Your Daily digest for Lifehack"

How to categorise those email types?

Answer (score 2):

When you're looking at your list of email messages, simply drag-and-drop<sup>1</sup> one of these messages on to the tab where you want it to be categorized.

That helps train the machine-learning algorithms how to categorize messages. It's not perfect; sometimes you need to have done it several times. Other times it seems to revert. But such instances are rare in my experience.

Below you can see I'm dragging a message from "Updates" to "Social".

[image: dropping on another tab]

(See also "Move messages between tabs" at [Gmail Support: Inbox tabs and category labels](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016/).)

If you don't want to rely on computer brains to work this out and/or you want to be more explicit about specific messages, "Categorize as" is an action you can take with a Gmail filter. Just [create a filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579) like you would for other messages and choose the category you want.

[image: Categorize as action on Filter dialog]

---

<sup>1</sup> You'll need a fairly modern browser. If you're using something that doesn't support drag-and-drop here, check the messages you want to re-categorize and select the category in the "Move to" menu.